# Custom ValidationAttribute Data Annotation: return NO rules from GetClientValidationRules

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a custom ValidationAttribute that implements IClientValidatable, and in my implementation of "GetClientValidationRules" I want to, given a certain condition, return NO rules.  I tried returning null, i get a null exception at the TextBoxFor.  I tried returning a new ModelClientValidationRule, complains about the rule being empty.  I just want to return nothing.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following? That'll return an empty list of rules.

```
return Enumerable.Empty<ModelClientValidationRule>()
```

Comment: Won't compile becuase Iterator cannot contain a return.  Is there an alternate syntax to return that?

Comment: Huh, can you post your code? (By editting your question, please!) The code I've given is supposed to go inside the method `GetClientValidationRules()` which is supposed to return a `IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule>`... the error message doesn't make much sense since the method has to return _something_...

Comment: I was mixing a yield return with a regular return, which produces the compilation error I mentioned.  It seems silly that the compiler can't differentiate but there's a reason I'm sure.  A better error message would help.  Now I always return IEnumerable and not yield return a single rule in both cases and yes, your solution works.  Thanks!